# Unpublished app from google play store it available in other sites / play store

Tags: android, google-app-engine, stored-procedures, google-play, app-store

I released an app in the Google Play Store. After a few months I unpublished that app. The problem now is that the same app is available in some other sites / Play Store. When I search the app name in Google, I can see the app and I can download it. The app is still unpublished in the app store.

How to solve this problem? Unpublished app cannot see any where.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

ask the site owner to take down your application.The will.But it will appear later.So basically there is no solution for your problem but ask site owner to take down the apk.

Comment: should be in comment

Answer (score 0):

This site are doing fake advertistment for you!
They are saying, that your app has more then 50.000 downloads and so on.
It´s just at the beginning, later if you register your app on this site, you have to pay for the fake download values.

PS:

> https://mobiles10.info/app/riftboy-dexter/de.hhn.laborgames.coffegame.riftboydexter/

This is a game, which i create with some students during my studies...

I'm sure, we have only 5 downloads, but this site says:
Average rating for Riftboy Dexter Game is 4.1/5 from total 137 user votes.
..

So don´t care about it.